# Is there a way to use UPDATE query with dynamic attributes in Spring Framework?

Tags: spring, rest, jpa, spring-boot, crud

I'm developing a REST server application using Spring Boot.

Just got a question while constructing an UPDATE query.

Currently my UPDATE query in UserRepository is like this;

```
@Modifying
@Transactional
@Query(value ="update User u set u.user_dob=:userDOB, u.user_lastname=:userLastName, u.user_firstname=:userFirstname, u.user_streetaddress=:userStreetAddress where d.driver_id=:driverId", nativeQuery = true)
void updateUser(@Param("userDOB") String userDOB, @Param("userLastName") String userLastName, @Param("userFirstName") String userFirstName, @Param("userStreetAddress") String userStreetAddress);
```

However, I don't like to list all the attributes of User in one UPDATE query.
Is there anyway to construct UPDATE query dynamically?

For example;

Update with

```
set u.user_dob=:userDOB, u.user_lastname=:userLastName, u.user_firstname=:userFirstname, u.user_streetaddress=:userStreetAddress
```

or

```
u.user_lastname=:userLastName, u.user_firstname=:userFirstname
```

using one update method.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Spring Data JPA (seems you do), your repository interface is probably extending JpaRepository interface.

In this case, you could simply use **save** method.

Here are some good examples: 
http://www.springbyexample.org/examples/spring-data-jpa-repository.html
http://www.springbyexample.org/examples/spring-data-jpa-code-example.html